# Is there a way to use a VirtualPC image from linux?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a nicely setup Windows XP image made on VirtualPC 2007. However, I currently need to use Linux (am using Lucid) for development. Is there a way in which I can use the VPC image from Linux - using either Virtualbox OSE or VMWare player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Sathya's link, I looked into available `vboxmanage` commands and found out that now you can actually even create a VHD with VirtualBox (so being able to use one seemed very logical). So I just converted the existing VHD to a fixed-size one. I created a new virtual machine from VirtualBox with the same settings - XP with 128MB RAM - made a backup of the VHD (just in case), and attached it to the new virtual machine. And it's working without any problems at all.

Answer (score 5):

You can use VirtualBox and [convert the images](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=3767&sid=5913550ffb21b7dc5b57b9cb573be88f#p3767)

```
vboxmanage convertdd the_disk.vhd the_disk.vdi
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems VirtualBox has come a long way since then. But the link definitely helped.